# How do I prevent this precision exception?

Tags: numerics

I have the following as the first step to a sequence.

```
x = 2 - GoldenRatio;
Ceiling[x + x^(1/2)]
```

It gets a precision exception.  The value is correct, but I would like to prevent the exception.  (If we subtract 0.000001 from x, everything is fine.)

Is there a way to limit the precision?  For one step only?

Edit: the sequence where 2-GoldenRatio is the seed.

```
x = 2 - GoldenRatio; t = Table[(x = Ceiling[x + x^(1/2)]), {2000}];
```

If ceiling is removed the first step works fine.  However, I need the ceiling for alternate steps.

Edit2: $0 < x \leq 2-\phi$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. $\textit{When x = 2 - $\phi$, the first step equals $1$}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you what you need:

```
x = N[2 - GoldenRatio]
Ceiling[x + x^(1/2)]

0.381966
1
```

This doesn't get a precision exception.

This as per the update of your question also works without getting an error.

```
x = N[2 - GoldenRatio];
t = Table[(x = Ceiling[x + x^(1/2)]), {2000}];
```

Comment: That's the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make a value inexact:

```
x = 2` - GoldenRatio;
x + x^(1/2)
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

Or use `FullSimplify`:

```
x = 2 - GoldenRatio;
x + x^(1/2) // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> 1
> ```